# How to increase relations depth in strapi API response?

Tags: api, strapi

I use Strapi for building API for my small app. In a model, I have the following entities:

*Article*, *Article Translation*, *Tag*, *Tag translation*.
One *Article* has Many *Article Translations*. Each *Article Translation* has Many *Tags*. Each *Tag* has Many *Tags translations*.

My problem is that when I make a GET-request to *Article*, I don't receive *Tags translations*. I suppose they are too deep for Strapi. If I just make a GET-request to *Tag* or to *Tag Translation*, the response is correct.

How can I increase the depth of relations responses?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override the controller, something like this

```
module.exports = {
   /**
   * Promise to fetch all records
   *
   * @return {Promise}
   */
  find: async (ctx) => {
    return strapi.query('model-name').find(ctx.query, [
        "entries",
        "entries.image",
        "entries.expandable_children",
        "entries.expandable_children.image",
        "entries.expandable_children.localizations",
        "entries.localizations",
        "localizations"
    ]);
  },
  findOne: async (ctx) => {
    const { id } = ctx.params;
    return strapi.query('model-name').findOne({ id }, [
        "entries",
        "entries.image",
        "entries.expandable_children",
        "entries.expandable_children.image",
        "entries.expandable_children.localizations",
        "entries.localizations",
        "localizations"
    ]);
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of overriding any controllers, you can try adding the *Tag Translation* field under the populate section of your request URL.

```
eg: populate[0]=article.tag.tag-translation
```

If you use **GraphQL** this would much easier. I used something similar in an app I developed and it worked fine.